# Creating C# TCP server

Tags: c#, tcp, client, tcplistener

I am trying to make a Server app and client app to connect through internet using C#.
Here is my Server app...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    private byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    private int size = 1024;
    private Socket server;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ControlBox = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8001);
        server.Bind(iep);
        server.Listen(1);
        server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn), server);
        textBox1.Text = "Server Started!! \r\nWaiting for client...";
    }

    void AcceptConn(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket oldserver = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = oldserver.EndAccept(iar);
        textBox1.Text = "Connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        string stringData = "Welcome to my server";
        byte[] message1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData);
        client.BeginSend(message1, 0, message1.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
    }

    void SendData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        int sent = client.EndSend(iar);
        client.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), client);
    }

    void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        int recv = client.EndReceive(iar);
        if (recv == 0)
        {
            client.Close();
            textBox1.Text = "Waiting for client...";
            server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn), server);
            return;
        }
        string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        listBox1.Items.Add(receivedData);
        byte[] message2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(receivedData);
        client.BeginSend(message2, 0, message2.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                     new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server.Close();
        //server.Shutdown();
    }

    void ButtonStopOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

}

And here is my Client app...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private TextBox newText;
    private TextBox conStatus;
    private ListBox results;
    private Socket client;
    private byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    private int size = 1024;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ControlBox = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Connecting...";
        Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                              SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.3"), 8001);
        //IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("41.232.217.55"), 8001);
        newsock.BeginConnect(iep, new AsyncCallback(Connected), newsock);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Clear();
        client.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                     new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.Close();
        textBox2.Text = "Disconnected";
    }

    void Connected(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            client.EndConnect(iar);
            textBox2.Text = "Connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            client.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None,
                          new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), client);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Error connecting";
        }
    }

    void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        int recv = remote.EndReceive(iar);
        string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        listBox1.Items.Add(stringData);
    }

    void SendData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        int sent = remote.EndSend(iar);
        remote.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None,
                      new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), remote);
    }
}
```

}

I understand that the server app can use IPaddress.Any but the client must be specific to reach the server.

My problem is that i cant connect form another computer outside the local addressing (192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2,....). I want the client to be able to connect to my server using my remote IP (41.232.217.55).

Comment: You'll probably have to forward the ports from your firewall to the computer running the server application.

Comment: This is called NAT traversal and has really nothing to do with C# (or even programming, unless you are trying to automate it), as it is a general networking technique.